# Crontab running issue

Tags: linux, cron

I have 500 php files i want to make a crontab to run them automatically (they store XML data in my database) my problem is :

when I make a crontab for each php file it works fine. the command like this:

```
* * * * * php /home/username/public_html/codes/php0.php
```

But when I want to run a shell script including all my php files like this :

```
* * * * * bash /home/username/public_html/codes/php.sh
```

it does not run.

php.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

php php0.php
echo php0
php php1.php
echo php1
php php2.php
echo php2
.
.
.
```

Is it possible to wrap php files with bash script? and if yes why does not work am I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably not running in the directory you believe you are.

So replace temporarily  `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/bin/sh -vx`
and add a

```
  pwd
```

at the beginning of your script (that is, the 2nd line)

Then perhaps add a

```
 cd /home/username/public_html/codes
```

or maybe define a variable and use it:

```
 mycodedir=/home/username/public_html/codes
 php $mycodedir/php0.php
 echo php0
```

etc...

I suggest to read the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) (even if it does have weaknesses).

Comment: sorry I do not know any thing about Linux commands so excuse me what is pwd and where to add it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you have relative paths in your `php.sh`. The following line

```
php php0.php
```

means that `php` will look for the `php0.php` file in the current working directory.  In a cron job, the working directory is usually `/`, i.e. the file system root. To check what the working directory really is, you can use the `pwd` command.

So your `php.sh` script looks for a file `php0.php` in your file system root, but the file is in `/home/username/public_html/codes/`.

If you use *absolute* paths in your `php.sh`, the current working directory does not matter. So simply add absolute paths in your `php.sh`. The file will look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

php /home/username/public_html/codes/php0.php
echo php0
php /home/username/public_html/codes/php1.php
echo php1
php /home/username/public_html/codes/php2.php
echo php2
.
.
.
```